# How can multiple developers work on the same branch using git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

The problem we're running into is that we have our main `development` branch.  And we have a ticket that relies on multiple tickets in order to get put into the `development` branch.  So lets say ticket `A` relies on ticket `B` and `C` in order to be merged into `development`.

The way we've been handling this is making an `A` branch off of `development` then branching `B` and `C` off of `A`.  The problem is that we want to take updates of development into `A`, `B`, and `C` and we also want to take updates from `B` into `C` and vise versa.  How can we do this using `git rebase` without having everyone delete their local A branch when someone does a `git push --force` of `A` rebase after taking changes from `development`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### TL;DR summary

History *is* commits.

Rebase means "copy commits, then try to forget the originals and use the copies instead".  This means "make up a new history".

Git repositories get *distributed* (widely copied).  New histories creating by rebasing only affect the one repository.  This is why you have to use `--force` during your push, to force another repository to accept the "history rewrite".  But that affects only *one* other copy, not *all* other copies.

There are some tricks you can use to mitigate the pain, but the pain itself does not really go away.  It's up to you to choose which kind of pain you prefer.  The main trick is to use `git rebase`: either avoid `git pull` entirely, or configure it to run `git rebase` as its second Git command.  But this only works to one level.

The alternative is not to use `--force`.  This is far simpler, but does leave you with tangled histories.  That still may be preferable.

#### Description

In Git, to a large extent, branch *names* don't matter.  They do get used here and there, for several purposes, but they are quite fluid and impermanent—very much *unlike* commits, which are permanent and can never, ever be changed (but *can* be copied!).  It therefore does you no good to, as you put it, "make an `A` branch off `development` and then branch `B` and `C` off `A`":  Git does not care about the *names*, because they keep changing; it only cares about the *commits*, which don't.

You start off with this:

```
...--e--f--g   <-- development
```

(since you used uppercase one-letter names for the branches, I switched to lowercase one-letter names for each commit here).  You then add several more names:

```
...--e--f--g   <-- development, A, B, C
```

Now as soon as someone—anyone—who has this repository structure, i.e., literally has these four branch names in *their* repository, does:

```
git checkout development
```

and makes some new commits, this is what happens in *their* repository:

```
...--e--f--g   <-- A, B, C
            \
             h--i  <-- development (HEAD)
```

The new commits go in, with each new commit recording its previous parent as usual.  The branch name that represents the *current* branch (which this user's Git has recorded in this user's HEAD file) says that the *current* branch in this repository is the one named `development`, so the label that this Git keeps re-setting to the new commits made, is `development`.  Hence the label `development` *in this repository* has advanced to point to the newest of the two new commits.

The other labels have not moved.

---

Now, in practice, every user has his or her *own* repository.  Users must coordinate with each other, and this also happens through branch names—but now there are at least *two* Gits involved, so there are *two or more sets of branch names*.  Everything must be viewed through this lens: I have *my* branches, you have *your* branches, and when I talk to you I call you my "remote" and I rename *your* branches so that they don't interfere with mine.

It's possible for every developer to talk directly to every other developer.  If your group has [the standard first three people named Alice, Bob, and Carol](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1323:_Protocol) for instance, Alice could have two remotes named Bob and Carol, Bob could have two remotes named Alice and Carol, and Carol could have two remotes with, well, the obvious names.  This obviously scales poorly: with a group of 30 developers, everyone has 29 remotes.

So, you probably have one centralized server, possibly even on a fancy hosting site like GitHub.  This lets everyone have just *one* remote, which they all invariably call `origin`, since Git automatically uses that name unless you tell it to use something else.

This is where names like `origin/master` and `origin/development` come from, and is why we use the name `origin` when we `git fetch origin` and `git push origin <branch>`.  That's simply a common remote: a place for everyone to share his or her commits.

The tricky part here is that this `origin` Git repository is, well, a *Git repository*.  So it has commits, which are permanent but have awful, awkward hash-ID names like `9b00c5a...` and `badbeef...` and so on, that no one could remember; so it also has branch *names*, like `development`.

A branch name's *main* function is to remember one of these commit hash IDs.  This is why I drew the graphs above the way I drew them: the branch names "point to" the *tip* commit of their corresponding branches.

Note that one commit can be, and quite often is, on multiple branches simultaneously.  If you add a new branch name pointing to commit `i` (the current tip of `development`), suddenly all commits that used to be on `development` such as `e--f--g--h--i`) are now on this new branch too.  Delete this new branch name, and commits `h` and `i`, which were on exactly two branches, are now on just one branch.

A branch name has a secondary function: by letting Git *find* one particular commit, it *protects* that commit from being reaped by the Grim Collector, Git's "garbage collector" or "gc".  That commit then protects all of its history—all the previous commits leading up to the branch tip.  Since Git normally moves branch names by accreting new commits at the tip, the new commit (protected by the branch name) protects the old tip, which protects the even-older tip, all the way back to the very first commit ever.

Note that Git works backwards: we always start from the tip and work backwards through the history—the commits—by finding each commit's parent.  Each commit "points back" to its parent, and that sequence of commits *is* the history.  This is what `git log` shows us; and `gitk` or a graphical viewer, or using `--graph` with `git log`, shows us the connections from commits to their parents.

A parent with two immediate children forms a branch in the graph.  For this branch to continue to exist, both forks need a name right now.  Let's `git checkout B` (get on the `B` branch) and make a new commit to make this happen:

```
             j   <-- B (HEAD)
            /
...--e--f--g   <-- A, C
            \
             h--i  <-- development
```

The parent here is `g` and the two children are `h` and `j`.  The current branch *name*, `B`, has moved: it now points to `j`.

If we now check out branch `C` and make a new commit or two, the picture becomes harder to draw, because we need to leave `A` pointing to commit `g` and ASCII art doesn't really have that much room:

```
             j   <-- B
            /_------ A
...--e--f--g--k--l  <-- C (HEAD)
            \
             h--i  <-- development
```

Again, though, we're assuming that all this happens in *one* repository—in a sort of vacuum where no *other* repositories exist.  It's also getting much too hard to draw, so let's drop back to having just branches name `B` and `development`s, and let's assume that we have, somehow, gotten into this state both on the repository at `origin` and at one person's repository—Alice's, say—so that we now have this in both the Alice and `origin` repositories:

```
...--e--f--g--j  <-- B
            \
             h--i  <-- development
```

Now if Bob runs `git fetch` from `origin`, and assuming Bob has no branches of his own yet (he must have at least one, we're just not drawing it in), this is what Bob gets:

```
...--e--f--g--j  <-- origin/B
            \
             h--i  <-- origin/development
```

That is, Bob's Git remembers, for Bob, what was in `origin` the last time Bob ran `git fetch origin` (NB: let's avoid `git pull` for now, but note that the first thing it does is run `git fetch origin`).  It does so by *renaming* the branches it finds on `origin`, so that they're not branches any more.

If Bob now runs `git checkout development`, Bob's Git finds that Bob doesn't *have* a `development` yet.  It searches through Bob's repository and finds `origin/development`, which sure looks a lot like `development`, so Bob's Git *creates* a *new* `development`, pointing to the same commit that `origin/development` points to.  Now Bob has this:

```
...--e--f--g--j  <-- origin/B
            \
             h--i  <-- development (HEAD), origin/development
```

If Bob runs `git checkout master` he'll still have the names `origin/B` (pointing to `j`), `development` (pointing to `i`), and `origin/development` (pointing to `i` too); but he will check out some other commit (maybe `d` that we haven't drawn in?), and attach his HEAD to `master`.

You might wonder why Alice doesn't have these `origin/` names.  The truth is, she *does*.  She has `origin/B` pointing to `j`, and `origin/development` pointing to `i`.  Note that Alice already *also* has her own `B` and `development` names.  Bob does not (yet) have his own `B`, only his own `development`.

(The repository over on `origin`, though, probably doesn't have any `origin/` names.  It just has its own branches.  This is because it does not have a user using it; that non-existent user does not run `git fetch origin`.)

---

Let's go back over to Alice now, and suppose Alice runs a `git rebase` to rebase `development` so that it comes after Alice's `B`:

```
$ git checkout development
$ git rebase B
```

What `git rebase` does is *copy* some commits.

The way it chooses *which commits to copy* is to look at the current branch, and then to look at its arguments.

The current branch is `development` and the argument is `B`.  Here's what Alice has right now (which is remarkably similar to what Bob has):

```
...--e--f--g--j  <-- B, origin/B
            \
             h--i  <-- development (HEAD), origin/development
```

The commits that `git rebase` is to copy are those that are on the *current branch* (`development`), *except for* any commits that are on branch `B`.  Well, commits `...--e--f-g--j--i` are on `development` and `...--e--f--g--j` are on `B`.  So Git subtracts `j` from the `e--f--g--h--i` set—that's easy, there is no `j`, so nothing happens.  Then Git subtracts `g` from the set, and also `...--e--f`, leaving `h--i`.

These are the commits to be copied.

The *place* where they will go, after being copied, is whatever commit `B` points to, i.e., they are to go after commit `j`.

Now Git makes the copies (using what Git calls "detached HEAD" mode):

```
                h'-i'   <-- HEAD
               /
...--e--f--g--j  <-- B, origin/B
            \
             h--i  <-- development, origin/development
```

These new copies have *different hash IDs*.  They are different commits!  They are *copies* (with some changes) of the original `h--i`, hence we call them `h'-i'` here.  The originals are still in there, because there are still names holding them frozen into place.

The last step of `git rebase` is to forcibly move the original branch name, `development`, to point to the tip-most copied commit, and re-attach your HEAD:

```
                h'-i'   <-- development (HEAD)
               /
...--e--f--g--j  <-- B, origin/B
            \
             h--i  <-- origin/development
```

The name that still keeps `h--i` around is `origin/development`.  Alice's Git now translates `development` into "commit `i'`" (whatever its new hash ID is), so the history of her rewritten `development` ends with `i'`, goes back to `h'`, then goes back to `j`, `g`, `f`, etc., in Git's usual backwards fashion.

#### Force push

If Alice now tries to `git push origin development`, she gets a *rejection*.  This is because the Git over at `origin` still has this:

```
...--e--f--g--j  <-- B
            \
             h--i  <-- development
```

Alice's Git sends over commits `h'` and `i'`, i.e., the commits she has that `origin` doesn't, along with a proposal:

```
                h'-i'   <-- proposal: move development here
               /
...--e--f--g--j  <-- B
            \
             h--i  <-- development
```

Origin's Git looks at the proposal and says: uh, no, that's not a "fast forward".  DENIED!

Remember earlier we saw that Git branches grew by accreting new commits onto their ends.  If Alice were pushing new commits that *added on* to `h--i`, that would be OK: that's a "fast forward" operation (adding several commits at once, rather than one at a time).  But she's pushing these new commits and then proposing to yank `development` away from `h--i` entirely, and that's *not* OK: that's not a "fast forward".

But Alice can use `--force` to make it a command, rather than a proposal; and then, as long as origin's Git doesn't object too much, origin's Git obeys and changes its repository to look like this:

```
                h'-i'   <-- development
               /
...--e--f--g--j  <-- B
```

This is the beginning of the pain for everyone but Alice (and `origin` itself).

Note that commits `h--i` are just gone from the repository at `origin`.  (If the server at `origin` is using Git's *reflogs*, the reflogs there will retain them for a while.  By default, servers *do not* keep reflogs, though.)

#### Now Bob feels the pain of an upstream rebase

At this point, when Bob runs `git fetch origin`—remember, if you (or Bob) is using `git pull`, you are really running `git fetch origin` first—Bob gets the updated `origin/development`, because these `origin/whatever` names just slavishly follow whatever has happened on the remote repository.  That's what Bob wants: *Bob's* branches are not named `origin/whatever`; those `origin/whatever`s are *remote-tracking branches* (always separate from all of Bob's branches).

So, now Bob has this (let's assume Bob has back on `development` so that it is his HEAD too):

```
                h'-i'   <-- origin/development
               /
...--e--f--g--j  <-- origin/B
            \
             h--i  <-- development (HEAD)
```

It's up to Bob to (somehow) figure out that there was what we call an *upstream rebase*: `origin/development` used to point to commit `i` and now points to commit `i'` instead.  Bob didn't write commits `h--i` himself, he only has them on his `development` because that's where his Git set his `development` back when he ran the `git checkout development` that *created* his `development`.

But it sure looks, to Bob's Git, like Bob wrote those commits himself, because `origin/development` doesn't have them.

In this particular case (Bob has no work of his own), Bob can just run `git reset --hard origin/development` to make his Git move his `development` to match `origin/development`.  But what if Bob *did* make a new commit on `development`?  Let's draw this situation:

```
                h'-i'   <-- origin/development
               /
...--e--f--g--j  <-- origin/B
            \
             h--i--k  <-- development (HEAD)
```

What Bob has to do now is to do his own kind of `git rebase`.  He needs to *copy* his commit `k` to come after `i'`.

#### Automatic upstream rebase handling with fork-point

Git has a feature in which it uses the reflogs (not illustrated above) to *try* to figure out which commits are actually Bob's.  It usually just works: Bob's Git can figure out what commit `k` is Bob's, and commits `h--i` are left over from an earlier `origin/development` value.

Hence, Bob can run:

```
git rebase --fork-point origin/development
```

while Bob is on (Bob's) `development`.  The `--fork-point` option makes Git try to figure all this out.

Note that `--fork-point` is the *default* for some rebases, and not for others.  The idea is to make all this work seamlessly and automatically.  In practice, the seams show all over the place.

The place where `--fork-point` gets used automatically is with `git rebase` with no arguments, or the `git rebase` that `git pull` runs *if* you make `git pull` run `git rebase`.

By default, `git pull` runs `git merge` instead ... and that *merges* the original `h--i` with the new `h'--i'`, bringing back those commits Alice was trying to remove with her history rewrite!  So either don't use `git pull` at all (my preference), or set it up to use `git rebase` as its second step.  (Its first step is *always* `git fetch`.)

Unfortunately, all of this only works when you automatically rebase your `development` on your `origin/development` by virtue of your `development` having `origin/development` set as its *upstream*.  If you run an explicit `git rebase origin/development`, that *turns off* the `--fork-point` option, and you must specify `--fork-point` too.  It's all quite confusing ... which is probably why some prefer `git pull`, which hides all this from you.  The problem is, it's all a bit too raw to hide: it doesn't always work, and you need to know what is happening, and why, so you can fix it.

#### When the automatic stuff doesn't work, you must rebase by hand

If none of the automation will do the job, each user (Bob, Carol, Dmitry, and so on) can do a manual `git rebase`, or `git rebase -i`.  An interactive rebase allows the user to strip out commits that should not be copied, such as the `h--i` set in the example above.  It's not the most fun exercise.  It does leave you with a clean history; but it's up to you to decide whether this kind of clean history is worth the pain.

Comment: brilliant explanation! Strongly recommended to anyone who wants to absorb git rebase by heart